# Payment gateway with the lowest transaction fee?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I'm with a small startup that is about to start accepting micropayments of $3-5.  Which payment gateway has the lowest transaction fees?

**NOTE**: Payment gateway must be able to process delayed payments (accepting cards and authorizing them, but not charging until several days or a week later).

Thanks for the help SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [pay pal](http://paypal.com). It has 95 million users. It has various solutions for people like you.

Very reliable service.

Check out [this page](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/order/paypal/paypal-14.html) for more inputs.

Comment: Moneybookers is the lesser known alternative, hence has to be a little cheaper.

Comment: For small business, I think I would choose a reliable service by spending a few extra bucks rather than choosing a lesser known service and going through hassles.

Comment: Hey Vanchinathan, thanks for the response!  Paypal charges $.30 +2.9% per transaction, which is almost 13% of the payment itself! Authorize.net only charges $.10 per transaction, but is more difficult to setup I think.

Comment: https://micropayments.paypal-labs.com/ Can you please look at this url. I think they have a special scheme for micropayments. Paypal is very much developer and customer friendly.